# Pytables duplicates 2.5 giga rows

Tags: python, duplicates, hdf5, pytables

I currently have a .h5 file, with a table in it consisting of three columns: a text columns of 64 chars, an UInt32 column relating to the source of the text and a UInt32 column which is the xxhash of the text. The table consists of ~ 2.5e9 rows

I am trying to find and count the duplicates of each text entry in the table - essentially merge them into one entry, while counting the instances. I have tried doing so by indexing on the hash column and then looping through `table.itersorted(hash)`, while keeping track of the hash value and checking for collisions - very similar to [finding a duplicate in a hdf5 pytable with 500e6 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743135/finding-a-duplicate-in-a-hdf5-pytable-with-500e6-rows]). I did not modify the table as I was looping through it but rather wrote the merged entries to a new table - I am putting the code at the bottom.

Basically the problem I have is that the whole process takes significantly too long - it took me about 20 hours to get to iteration #5 4e5. I am working on a HDD however, so it is entirely possible the bottleneck is there. Do you see any way I can improve my code, or can you suggest another approach? Thank you in advance for any help.

P.S. I promise I am not doing anything illegal, it is simply a large scale leaked password analysis for my Bachelor Thesis.

````
ref = 3 #manually checked first occuring hash, to simplify the below code
gen_cnt = 0
locs = {}


print("STARTING")
for row in table.itersorted('xhashx'):
    gen_cnt += 1 #so as not to flush after every iteration
    ps = row['password'].decode(encoding = 'utf-8', errors = 'ignore')

    if row['xhashx'] == ref:
        if ps in locs:
            locs[ps][0] += 1
            locs[ps][1] |= row['src']

        else:
            locs[ps] = [1, row['src']]


    else:
        for p in locs:
            fill_password(new_password, locs[ps]) #simply fills in the columns, with some fairly cheap statistics procedures
            new_password.append()   

        if (gen_cnt > 100):
            gen_cnt = 0
            new_table.flush()  

        ref = row['xhashx']```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset is 10x larger than the referenced solution (2.5e9 vs 500e6 rows). Have you done any testing to identify where the time is spent? The `table.itersorted()` method may not be linear - and might be resource intensive. (I don't have any experience with itersorted.)

Here is a process that might be faster:

1. Extract a NumPy array of the hash field (column `xhashx` 
   )
2. Find the unique hash values
3. Loop thru the unique hash values and extract a NumPy array of
   rows that match each value
4. Do your uniqueness tests against the rows in this extracted array
5. Write the unique rows to your new file

**Code for this process below:**
Note: This has been not tested, so may have small syntax or logic gaps

```
# Step 1: Get a Numpy array of the 'xhashx' field/colmu only:
hash_arr = table.read(field='xhashx')
# Step 2: Get new array with unique values only:
hash_arr_u = np.unique(hash_arr)

# Alternately, combine first 2 steps in a single step
hash_arr_u = np.unique(table.read(field='xhashx'))

# Step 3a: Loop on rows unique hash values
for hash_test in hash_arr_u :

# Step 3b: Get an array with all rows that match this unique hash value
     match_row_arr = table.read_where('xhashx==hash_test')

# Step 4: Check for rows with unique values
# Check the hash row count. 
# If there is only 1 row, uniqueness tested not required  
     if match_row_arr.shape[0] == 1 :
     # only one row, so write it to new.table

     else :
     # check for unique rows
     # then write unique rows to new.table

##################################################
# np.unique has an option to save the hash counts
# these can be used as a test in the loop
(hash_arr_u, hash_cnts) = np.unique(table.read(field='xhashx'), return_counts=True)

# Loop on rows in the array of unique hash values
for cnt in range(hash_arr_u.shape[0]) :

# Get an array with all rows that match this unique hash value
     match_row_arr = table.read_where('xhashx==hash_arr_u(cnt)')

# Check the hash row count. 
# If there is only 1 row, uniqueness tested not required  
     if hash_cnts[cnt] == 1 :
     # only one row, so write it to new.table

     else :
     # check for unique rows
     # then write unique rows to new.table
```

Comment: Thank you for your well-structured response! I have not done any quantitative research into where itersorted takes the most time, but I tried doing some eyetests and came to the conclusion that a method similar to yours might be faster. I didnt think of the fact that I can hold the whole column of unique hash values in memory, so I ended up writing the unique hash values to a file and looping through that. This of course slows down the process again because of the extra file I/O and consequent disk reads. I will try your version and report back!

Comment: If you find table.read() of the entire 'xhashx' column is too large, you can do it incrementally in  aloop (loop1: rows 0->1e8; loop2: rows 1e8->2e8, etc). Just add the start= and stop= parameters to rabe.read(), next find the unique values, then add them to the hash_arr_u array. You will need to recheck for unique values after the loop is done.